# Creating resizable columns and rows with html, css, vanilla js

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I need to create table that has width of 100%. I want to be able to resize columns and rows in height and width. What's the best approach to it?

I tried few things, and this is my current js, it works okish on table with content width, but 100% width, not really. For example columns can overlap, when I drag second column to left, third one also drags and resizes.

```
const tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
for (let i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
  resizableGrid(tables[i]);
}

function resizableGrid(table) {
  const row = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
  const cols = row ? row.children : undefined;
  if (!cols) return;

  table.style.overflow = "hidden";

  const tableHeight = table.offsetHeight;

  for (let i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    const div = createDiv(tableHeight);
    cols[i].appendChild(div);
    cols[i].style.position = "relative";
    setListeners(div);
  }

  function setListeners(div) {
    let pageX, curCol, nxtCol, curColWidth, nxtColWidth;

    div.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
      curCol = e.target.parentElement;
      nxtCol = curCol.nextElementSibling;
      pageX = e.pageX;

      const padding = paddingDiff(curCol);

      curColWidth = curCol.offsetWidth - padding;
      if (nxtCol) nxtColWidth = nxtCol.offsetWidth - padding;
    });

    div.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
      e.target.style.borderRight = "2px solid #0000ff";
    });

    div.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
      e.target.style.borderRight = "";
    });

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
      if (e.pageX >= 0 && e.pageX < window.innerWidth - 10) {
  
        if (curCol) {
          const diffX = e.pageX - pageX;
          if (nxtCol && diffX > 0)
            nxtCol.style.width = nxtColWidth - diffX + "px";

          curCol.style.width = curColWidth + diffX + "px";
        }
      }
    });

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
      curCol = undefined;
      nxtCol = undefined;
      pageX = undefined;
      nxtColWidth = undefined;
      curColWidth = undefined;
    });
  }

  function createDiv(height) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.top = 0;
    div.style.right = 0;
    div.style.width = "5px";
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.cursor = "col-resize";
    div.style.userSelect = "none";
    div.style.height = height + "px";
    return div;
  }

  function paddingDiff(col) {
    if (getStyleVal(col, "box-sizing") == "border-box") {
      return 0;
    }

    const padLeft = getStyleVal(col, "padding-left");
    const padRight = getStyleVal(col, "padding-right");
    return parseInt(padLeft) + parseInt(padRight);
  }

  function getStyleVal(elm, css) {
    return window.getComputedStyle(elm, null).getPropertyValue(css);
  }
}
```

**Snippet**

```js
const tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
for (let i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
  resizableGrid(tables[i]);
}

function resizableGrid(table) {
  const row = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
  const cols = row ? row.children : undefined;
  if (!cols) return;

  table.style.overflow = "hidden";

  const tableHeight = table.offsetHeight;

  for (let i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    const div = createDiv(tableHeight);
    cols[i].appendChild(div);
    cols[i].style.position = "relative";
    setListeners(div);
  }

  function setListeners(div) {
    let pageX, curCol, nxtCol, curColWidth, nxtColWidth;

    div.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
      curCol = e.target.parentElement;
      nxtCol = curCol.nextElementSibling;
      pageX = e.pageX;

      const padding = paddingDiff(curCol);

      curColWidth = curCol.offsetWidth - padding;
      if (nxtCol) nxtColWidth = nxtCol.offsetWidth - padding;
    });

    div.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
      e.target.style.borderRight = "2px solid #0000ff";
    });

    div.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
      e.target.style.borderRight = "";
    });

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
      if (e.pageX >= 0 && e.pageX < window.innerWidth - 10) {
  
        if (curCol) {
          const diffX = e.pageX - pageX;
          if (nxtCol && diffX > 0)
            nxtCol.style.width = nxtColWidth - diffX + "px";

          curCol.style.width = curColWidth + diffX + "px";
        }
      }
    });

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
      curCol = undefined;
      nxtCol = undefined;
      pageX = undefined;
      nxtColWidth = undefined;
      curColWidth = undefined;
    });
  }

  function createDiv(height) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.top = 0;
    div.style.right = 0;
    div.style.width = "5px";
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.cursor = "col-resize";
    div.style.userSelect = "none";
    div.style.height = height + "px";
    return div;
  }

  function paddingDiff(col) {
    if (getStyleVal(col, "box-sizing") == "border-box") {
      return 0;
    }

    const padLeft = getStyleVal(col, "padding-left");
    const padRight = getStyleVal(col, "padding-right");
    return parseInt(padLeft) + parseInt(padRight);
  }

  function getStyleVal(elm, css) {
    return window.getComputedStyle(elm, null).getPropertyValue(css);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
td, th {
  text-align: center;
  border: thin solid lightgray;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Caption</caption>
  <thead>
  <tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th><tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1A</td><td>1B</td><td>1C</td><td>1D</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2A</td><td>2B</td><td>2C</td><td>2D</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3A</td><td>3B</td><td>3C</td><td>3D</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4A</td><td>4B</td><td>4C</td><td>4D</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5A</td><td>5B</td><td>5C</td><td>5D</td></tr>
  </tbody>
    <tfoot>
  <tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th><tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```